# Node.js PayPal route for payment creation with customer responsible for transaction fee

Tags: node.js, paypal-sandbox, payment

```
paypal.payment.create(
    {
      intent: "sale",
      payer: {
        payment_method: "paypal",

      },
      redirect_urls: {
        return_url: returnUrl,
        cancel_url: cancelUrl,
      },
      transactions: [
        {
          amount: {
            total: price,
            currency: "USD", // replace with your currency code
          },
          description: description,
          }
        },
      ],
    },
    function (error, payment) {
      if (error) {
        console.dir(error.response.details);
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ error: "Unable to create PayPal payment" });
      } else {
        console.log("Create Payment Response");
        console.log(payment);
        // Redirect user to PayPal approval URL
        const approvalUrl = payment.links.find(
          (link) => link.rel === "approval_url"
        ).href;
        res.json({ approvalUrl: approvalUrl });
      }
    }
  );
```

I write route in nodejs to create a payment before execute it. How can I configure the payment that the client will responsible for the transaction fee? for example a custormer buy an item with the price $5, the seller receive $4.34 only. I want the customer to pay for the fee $0.66

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an obsolete API, v1/payments.

See the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) which includes a simple node example using the current v2/checkout/orders API for the initial creation and later payment capture. (This example also doesn't use any redirects for the approval step, as is proper with current web design principles.)

As for how to set the total amount and any line items indicating fees, see the v2/checkout/orders reference for all available parameters.

If whatever transaction fee you want to add is different from that for other payment methods, note that the [PayPal user agreement](https://www.paypal.com/us/legalhub/useragreement-full) does not permit this -- see its "No Surcharges" clause